# python point plotted with wrong coordinates on 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new in python. I am using python 3.7. I am trying to plot a single point on a 3d plot. The following although simple seems not to work. The point appears at wrong position (has wrong coordinates) on the plot. I do not understand why and how I could fix it. Thanks

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x =[10]
y =[8]
z =[10]

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Thank you for your response. I am adding here the plot I get....

[The outcome of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJeS0.png)

Comment: Please include the figure to show it's indeed incorrect.

Comment: I just ran your code: I see the point at (10, 8, 10), so looks good to me.

Comment: its 3d span image won't do much good

Comment: i am getting right output from your code

Comment: @Nihal perhaps not; it depends on how incorrect "wrong" is here (e.g., negative coordinates would show up immediately on a figure).

Comment: which coordinates are you expecting and where it is plotted?

Comment: For mee the point is correctly plotted. It might not look that way because maybe it's the 3D representation. If you move the plot you will see it correctly